# Accidentally rewrote a function from R base package, how to get back to default?

Tags: r, function, radix

I have accidentally rewrote `which()` function from base package in R by my own code. I need the original default `which()` function really badly but made a mistake of saving my workspace ( R Console) with the new (my own) definition of `which()` function ( that ironically uses the original `which()` function in it) so now which doesn't work at all.. How do I get the default `which()` back? Is there a way to find the source code for `which(`) function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try should work...

```
which <- base:::which
```

which is explicit, or you can use `rm( which )` [***thanks @mnel***]

Comment: or simply `rm(which)`

Comment: You only need 2 colons between `base` and `which`.

Comment: @TylerRinker Does it matter?

Comment: Not really, more information to others.  `::` for exported objects and `:::` for exported or non-exported objects.

Comment: Ok, so as I understand it `:::` for objects that have been deliberately *hidden*?

Comment: Yes, I have found many helpful functions are hidden by package authors. The convention appears to be not to call/re-use them as they're not as guaranteed (i.e. stable long-term) as the explicit `::` functions.